# How to filter list based on another list containing wildcards?

Tags: python, list, glob

How can I filter a list based on another list which contains partial values and wildcards?  The following example is what I have so far:

```
l1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
l2 = set(['*t1*', '*t4*'])

filtered = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
print filtered
```

This example results in:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
```

However, I am looking to limit the results based on `l2` to the following:

```
['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) module and a list comprehension with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> l1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
>>> l2 = set(['*t1*', '*t4*'])
>>> [x for x in l1 if not any(fnmatch(x, p) for p in l2)]
['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
```

Comment: Good one! I knew an approach using a `list` subclass which accepted regular expressions. Did not know this one.

Comment: It would be even better directly using `fnmatch.filter`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use filter() instead of the list comprehension, which may have the advantage that you can easily swap your filter function for more flexibility:

```
>>> l1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
>>> l2 = set(['*t1*', '*t4*'])
>>> filterfunc = lambda item: not any(fnmatch(item, pattern) for pattern in l2)
>>> filter(filterfunc, l1)
Out: ['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
>>> # now we don't like our filter function no more, we assume that our l2 set should match on any partial match so we can get rid of the star signs:
>>> l2 = set(['t1', 't4'])
>>> filterfunc = lambda item: not any(pattern in item for pattern in l2)
>>> filter(filterfunc, l1)
Out: ['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
```

This way, you can even generalize your filterfunc to work with several pattern sets:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def filterfunc(item, patterns):
    return not any(pattern in item for pattern in patterns)
>>> filter(partial(filterfunc, patterns=l2), l1)
Out: ['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
>>> filter(partial(filterfunc, patterns={'t1','test5'}), l1)
Out: ['test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

And of course you could easily upgrade your filterfunc to accept regular expressions in the pattern set, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach for your use-case is to simply test for the substring using Python's `in` (although this means removing your asterisks):

```
def remove_if_not_substring(l1, l2):
    return [i for i in l1 if not any(j in i for j in l2)]
```

so here's our data:

```
l1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
l2 = set(['t1', 't4'])
```

And calling our function with it:

```
remove_if_not_substring(l1, l2)
```

returns:

```
['test2', 'test3', 'test5']
```